# cwebp arguments in right order

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, image-conversion, webp

I am writing a command line of cwebp to convert .png image to .webp to achieve best picture with lowest size, but I am confused in right order and right values of arguments.

```
cwebp -preset photo -sns 75 -segments 4 -low_memory -partition_limit 30 -q 75 -f 100 -sharpness 0 -m 6 -alpha_q 100 -qrange 0 100 -alpha_filter best -alpha_method 1 -mt -exact -af -progress -short "a.png" -o "a.webp"
```

any guidance shall be highly appreciated